# Installed EXE not able to open by task scheduler

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, winforms-interop

I've developed a winform application using VS 2010. After installing this exe, I've scheduled it in task scheduler. At scheduled time, task showing running in task scheduler but it don't open(not launching) my exe. plz help.

Comment: you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869922/9766368), which I suggested for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your task go to the "General" tab 
and tick the checkbox "Run with highest privileges"

Comment: @loannis, Thnx for reply . I've make this changes... but not getting any solution